# After upgrading to 22.04 LTS, Perfect Privacy VPN manager no longer runs

Tags: vpn, 22.04

The only information I have is the fact that it does not launch. I click on the icon to launch the app (the PP VPN manager) and it sends me back to the desktop. Nothing else happens.

I have tried re-installing the application (sudo apt purge prefect-privacy-vpn) and re-installing it to no avail. I suspect the repo is not there, but I just don't know enough to troubleshoot this.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

If I run perfect-privacy-vpn from terminal, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (run):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/perfect_privacy/perfect-privacy-vpn/perfect_privacy_vpn/__init__.py", line 167, in run
    window = PerfectPrivacyVpnWindow.PerfectPrivacyVpnWindow()
  File "/opt/perfect_privacy/perfect-privacy-vpn/perfect_privacy_vpn_lib/Window.py", line 46, in __new__
    builder = get_builder('PerfectPrivacyVpnWindow')
  File "/opt/perfect_privacy/perfect-privacy-vpn/perfect_privacy_vpn_lib/helpers.py", line 41, in get_builder
    builder.add_from_file(ui_filename)
  File "/opt/perfect_privacy/perfect-privacy-vpn/perfect_privacy_vpn_lib/Builder.py", line 88, in add_from_file
    ele_widgets = tree.getiterator("object")
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try starting the application via command line in a terminal window. If errors are output, edit your question to show them. Copy and paste the errors, don't post a screenshot.

Comment: In addition to what @OrganicMarble said above, when you paste the errors and other output from the terminal, format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the [edit question window](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1423718/edit).

Comment: It looks like the VPN app is written in Python. Ubuntu 22.04 comes with a newer version of Python that is integral to the operating system. Thus it is not easy to replace it with an  older version of Python. You will have to ask the VPN service provider to update their app so that it works with Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading and trying out a few suggestions, here is the solution: To fix this issue, edit the python file /opt/perfect_privacy/perfect-privacy-vpn/perfect_privacy_vpn_lib/Builder.py

Edit `ele_widgets = tree.getiterator("object")`
to `ele_widgets = tree.iter("object")`

Edit `ele_signals = tree.getiterator("signal")`
to `ele_signals = tree.iter("signal")`

It worked for me! :)

Answer (score 2):

There currently is a problem between the Perfect Privacy Client and an incompatible version of Python on Ubuntu. They're currently working on it and will most likely release a patch which should fix the problem soon, else there will be a new client soon which won't have this incompatibilty issue.
You can read about the problem here on this forum post: https://board.perfect-privacy.com/threads/vpn-manager-crashed-unter-ubuntu-hirsute.4780/

If you really need to get Perfect Privacy working, you can either downgrade your Python version which might cause a lot of other trouble or you can use their OpenVPN Client in the terminal.
OpenVPN Guide from PP: https://www.perfect-privacy.com/en/manuals/linux_openvpn_terminal

(I got his information straight from the Perfect Privacy Support Team)